# navigator.geolocation.watchPosition not working correctly on ios device

Tags: ios, react-native, geolocation

I have a strange behavior and can not find a solution. In my React Native application I'm using the navigator.geolocation to determine the current position. My application is almost identical as the example in Facebook's Geolocation Code.

In the simulator my application works perfectly, but when I deploy it to my iphone the returning position (by getCurrentPosition and watchPosition) is not correctly. For example speed and heading is -1, accuracy is 65. Longitude and latitude seem to be valid, but not my real position (is in another country). 
It does not matter whether I deploy the application via debug or release to the iphone, it always reacts same.

But if I start for example TomTom and put this application in the background, and then start my GeolocationExample application, everything works as it should.

My application I have created as follows:

```
react-native init GeolocationExample
```

And then I replaced the file index.ios.js with this code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class GeolocationExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    initialPosition: 'unknown',
    lastPosition: 'unknown',
  };

  watchID: ?number = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        var initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
        this.setState({initialPosition});
      },
      (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
    );
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
      var lastPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
      this.setState({lastPosition});
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main}>
        <Text>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Initial position: </Text>
          {this.state.initialPosition}
        </Text>
        <Text>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Current position: </Text>
          {this.state.lastPosition}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main: {
    margin: 30
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('GeolocationExample', () => GeolocationExample);
```

Comment: @Tim Thank you for the corrections

Comment: any perfection for this ?

Answer (score 0):

1st option : add parameter

```
{enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000, accuracy:10 //ten meters not in the document}
```

2nd option : set line 28

```
#define RCT_DEFAULT_LOCATION_ACCURACY kCLLocationAccuracyBest //default was kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
```